# Trouble sorting a list with python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm somewhat new to python. I'm trying to sort through a list of strings and integers. The lists contains some symbols that need to be filtered out (i.e. ro!ad should end up road). Also, they are all on one line separated by a space. So I need to use 2 arguments; one for the input file and then the output file. It should be sorted with numbers first and then the words without the special characters each on a different line. I've been looking at loads of list functions but am having some trouble putting this together as I've never had to do anything like this. Any takers?

So far I have the basic stuff

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

try:
  infilename = sys.argv[1] #outfilename = sys.argv[2]
except:
  print "Usage: ",sys.argv[0], "infile outfile"; sys.exit(1)

ifile = open(infilename, 'r')
#ofile = open(outfilename, 'w')
data = ifile.readlines()
r = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (int(item.partition(' ')[0])
                               if item[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), item))
ifile.close()
print '\n'.join(r)
#ofile.writelines(r)
#ofile.close()
```

The output shows exactly what was in the file but exactly as the file is written and not sorted at all. The goal is to take a file (arg1.txt) and sort it and make a new file (arg2.txt) which will be cmd line variables. I used print in this case to speed up the editing but need to have it write to a file. That's why the output file areas are commented but feel free to tell me I'm stupid if I screwed that up, too! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Maybe you should separate lambda from the `key` argument to `sorted()`, so it is the separate function (written in a clear way).

Comment: You are sorting `data` in an unclear way: you take `item.partition`, but also you access its element `item[0]`. Did you mean `item.partition()[0].isdigit()`? But in that case a separate function would be better.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As I said, I'm pretty new to Python. I tried separating the lambda from the key a bit and it was rejected. When I used a data = set(['apple', 'zebra', 'carousel']) and tried that instead of using a file as the input, the sorted code worked perfectly. I just can't get it to work with a file rather than things I put into the script itself.

Comment: What file are you using as input?

Comment: It's a file from my work. One of our programs spits out a file that is...unorganized.

Comment: As an aside, a common pattern on Unix is to accept a list of input files as arguments (if empty, read standard input) and to always write to standard output. By observing this convention, you make it easier to use your tool as part of a more complex processing toolchain, and you don't have to worry about permissions, disk full etc when writing. (Granted, you are ignoring errors now, too, but it is certainly not good practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an issue like this, it's usually a good idea to check your data at various points throughout the program to make sure it looks the way you want it to. The issue here seems to be in the way you're reading in the file.

```
data = ifile.readlines()
```

is going to read in the entire file as a list of lines. But since all the entries you want to sort are on one line, this list will only have one entry. When you try to sort the list, you're passing a list of length 1, which is going to just return the same list regardless of what your key function is. Try changing the line to

```
data = ifile.readlines()[0].split()
```

You may not even need the key function any more since numbers are placed before letters by default. I don't see anything in your code to remove special characters though.

Comment: Fantastic! The second line was EXACTLY what I needed to get the algorithm to do it's sorting properly. Now I have to figure out the special characters issue. Thanks!

Comment: it probably wont order numerics right (eg: "100" "200","23","3","45","5")

Comment: So far it does everything I need it to do except get rid of the special characters. I'm trying the re.sub but I keep getting errors. I'm probably doing something wrong. Anyone got a fun solution for that so I don't have to take a shotgun to my computer? lol

Comment: re.sub should take care of what you're trying to do, but some special characters have special meanings in regexs so you'll probably have to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

since they are  on the same line you dont really need readlines

```
with open('some.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()  #now data = "item 1 item2 etc..."
```

you can use re to filter out unwanted characters

```
import re
data = "ro!ad"
fixed_data = re.sub("[!?@$]","",data)
```

partition maybe overkill

```
data = "hello 23frank sam wilbur"
my_list = data.split() # ["hello","23frank","sam","wilbur"]
print sorted(my_list)
```

however you will need to do more to force numbers to sort maybe something like

```
numbers = [x for x in my_list if x[0].isdigit()]
strings = [x for x in my_list if not x[0].isdigit()]
sorted_list = sorted(numbers,key=lambda x:int(re.sub("[^0-9]","",x))) + sorted(strings(
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am liking the special characters part especially. I am just wondering how to use that to remove them from a file that was used. Kind of like a final filter before writing to another file.

Comment: You should remove the specials before sorting, unless you specifically want them to affect the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, they are all on one line separated by a space.

So your file contains a single line?

> data = ifile.readlines()

This makes `data` into a list of the lines in your file. All 1 of them.

> r = sorted(...)

This makes `r` the sorted version of that list.

To get the words from the line, you can `.read()` the entire file as a single string, and `.split()` it (by default, it splits on whitespace).